# How to overcome AccessControlException: access denied .. "modifyThreadGroup"?

Tags: java, security, applet, accesscontrolexception

How to overcome `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")`?

```
Warning: Applet API and AppletViewer are deprecated.
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
        at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:895)
        at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:335)
        at java.desktop/sun.applet.AppletSecurity.checkAccess(AppletSecurity.java:324)
        at java.base/java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:313)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:433)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:388)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:503)
        at app1.start(app1.java:13)
        at java.desktop/sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:466)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: 1) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. ..

Comment: .. 4) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).